# Including a directory using PyInstaller

Tags: python, installation, include, pyinstaller, packaging

All of the documentation for PyInstaller talks about including individual files.

Is it possible to include a directory, or should I write a function to create the include array by traversing my include directory?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is also the official supported option using `Tree()`:

*[Pyinstaller: generate -exe file + folder (in --onefile mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602727/pyinstaller-generate-exe-file-folder-in-onefile-mode/20677118#20677118)*

*[The TOC and Tree Classes](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced-topics.html#the-toc-and-tree-classes)*

Comment: Thank you for sharing, using [the Tree class](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#the-tree-class) solved it for me in an elegant way. Now I just need this one line: `a.datas += Tree('./dir_to_include', prefix='dir_to_include')`

Comment: yep, I think it is just not documented well-enough, but this open-source, so PRs are welcome :)

Answer (score 23):

Paste the following after `a = Analysis()` in the spec file to traverse a directory recursively and add all the files in it to the distribution.

```
##### include mydir in distribution #######
def extra_datas(mydir):
    def rec_glob(p, files):
        import os
        import glob
        for d in glob.glob(p):
            if os.path.isfile(d):
                files.append(d)
            rec_glob("%s/*" % d, files)
    files = []
    rec_glob("%s/*" % mydir, files)
    extra_datas = []
    for f in files:
        extra_datas.append((f, f, 'DATA'))

    return extra_datas
###########################################

# append the 'data' dir
a.datas += extra_datas('data')
```

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't really get it. I have a directory called `~/Scripts`. My data is stored in `~/Scripts/Data`. Should I substitute `a.datas += extra_datas('data')` by `a.datas += extra_datas('Data')`?

Comment: If your pyInstaller script is also in `Scripts` and you call it with `python mybuildscript.py` from within `Scripts` then yes, you should substitute with `Data`, otherwise use `.` and `..` to navigate the directory tree.

Answer (score 19):

The problem is easier than you can imagine. Try this:

`--add-data="path/to/folder/*;."`

Comment: This will include all of the files in path/to/folder/, and all files in sub-folders, in the root of your pyinstaller output. However, any sub-folder structure won't be kept - all files will be flattened to the root. If you want to include the files in their same directory structure (but it still won't keep sub-folder structure), you can use `--add-data="path/to/folder/*;path/to/folder/"`

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can just add directories to the Analysis object and they get copied across.

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             datas = [('test/dir', 'test/dir')],
             ...)
```

Comment: At least for pyinstaller 4.2 the datas field need to be added as a tuple. If you want to add multiple folders it needs to be something like:
`... datas = [('test/dir', 'test/dir'),('test2/dir', 'test2/dir')] ...`

Answer (score 8):

Just use `glob`:

```
from glob import glob

datas = []
datas += glob('/path/to/filedir/*')
datas += glob('/path/to/textdir/*.txt')

# ...

a.datas = datas
```

Answer (score 0):

You're better off copying the folder to your site-packages and calling it as an import in the respective script. Then pyinstaller will automatically include the packages into the process. Make sure to test the script through VS or your preferred Codeing IDE before

It's much easier than trying to rebuild the directory structure through command line. Although it is not reproduceable via requirements.txt workflow methods without additional coding it cleans up the workflow for python to exe compiling.

If you do decide to do it the hard way, you can use auto-py-to-exe to write the script and then copy and paste the entire "Current Command" section and past it into the command line. This will save you a lot of time typing and correcting things.

I'm 3 days in and finally produced a working standalone exe that reproduces a python script with selection menus that call to other python scripts using the former method. The latter method produces undesirable results.

I wouldn't recommend using --onefile argument if your script calls to other scripts or changes windows with implementations such as screen manager. It will most likely cause crashes or overload your system resources and be unable to function as desired.

Side Note: If your using kivy in any of your application it's best to use pyinstaller 5.6.2 which will avoid recursive issues associated with kivy implementation in your code.

Good luck. Hope this helps.