# Pyinstaller: generate -exe file + folder (in --onefile mode)

Tags: python, user-interface, exe, pyinstaller, packaging

Now i'm working with Pyinstaller.
I have an script which get images from a img folder..

```
/python
|----/img
|----|----icon1.ico
|----|----icon2.ico
|----maint.py
```

My script to generate .exe is

```
pyinstaller.py --windowed --noconsole --clean --onefile maint.py
```

the problem is that only generate the .exe file but the whole folder /img is omitted.

**Question: which aditional syntax do I need to put in the previous line in order to get automatically the .exe file + /img folder?**

I mean: that after execution of pyinstaller.py script, with all arguments, I must see in the /dist folder: the .exe file + the /img folder with all icons or bitmaps files I have for my application

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "to get automatically the .exe file + /img folder"?

Comment: Just copy that folder to `/dist` once the compilation process suceeded.

Comment: @Blender I mean: that after execution of pyinstaller.py script, with all arguments, I must see in the /dist folder: the .exe file + the /img folder with all icons or bitmaps files I have for my application

Comment: @poke Yeah, that is one alternative, but manually. I was looking for a solution with the same command. Sometimes, I will not have privileges to copy and paste a folder into the /dist folder.

Comment: If *you* don’t have the privileges to do so, then the `pyinstaller.py` which *you run* won’t have those privileges either. In any case, just write a deploy script that (a) calls pyinstaller and (b) copies the files.

Comment: @poke Thanks for your answer. But again, I look for a solution embedded in the Pyinstaller commands if it's possible.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is how I managed to solve the issue:

I'm working with current version of PYInstaller + Python 2.67 with Sublime Text as Editor.

1. In case your Py script requires some files, icons, images, you must include a function which retrieves these files from the project folder (in development) or form the temporary data folder (in case of deployment). This script MUST be in your code exactly in the part which you put the relatives paths in order to get the resources. Please follow exactly [this guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790741).
2. After the previous code, you must execute for the first time the pyinstaller command -as I post in my question-.
3. Now, open your .spec file generated after execution of the PYInstaller (located in `PYinstaller/YourAppName/`) command and add, after `a.binaries` line, the next line into the `EXE()` function:

   ```
   exe = EXE(pyz,
             a.scripts,
             a.binaries,
             Tree('..\\python\\images', prefix='images\\'),
   ....
   ```

   Keep in mind that in `Tree(...)` function the first argument is the folder to put outside: **which means that I want to include all the content of this folder** (notice that I'm putting a relative path respect to the AppStart.py file) **into the file's container of my .EXE file.**
4. After that modification re-execute the pyinstaller command, but in this case pointing to my `.SPEC` file:

   ```
   pyinstaller.py --windowed --noconsole --clean --onefile AppStart\AppStart.spec
   ```

And finally my App can be executed as executable without need to copy and paste all external folders as someone mentioned. **But as always I consider the good-practical way.**

Thanks for your support.

Comment: This is the most reliable way I have found to include full directories! Look what people are doing without this option :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/12033695/2230844

Comment: The answer doesn't answer the initial question. There is no way to tell pyinstaller to copy files or directories in the dist directory by itself, instead of adding them to the bundle?

Comment: This answer should be honored for all PyInstaller users out there. This is the only solution that worked on my end, despite numerous workaround answers.

Comment: I am getting this if running directly on a spec file:
makespec options not valid when a .spec file is given

Answer (score 2):

You can also run pyinstaller within another python script then use `shutil.copytree()` to move the folders over after. Or use `shutil.copyfile()` for individual files.

```
import PyInstaller.__main__
import shutil

PyInstaller.__main__.run([
    'YourProgram.py',
    '--icon=UI/Your_Icon.ico',
    '--onefile',
    '--noconsole',
], )

shutil.copytree('path/', 'dist/path')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve many issues to get this working. For example:

- Getting the right resource path
- Adding data

The first issue is (as mentionned) solved by adjusting paths depending on execution mode.

```py
def app_path(path):
    frozen = 'not'
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
            # we are running in executable mode
            frozen = 'ever so'
            app_dir = sys._MEIPASS
    else:
            # we are running in a normal Python environment
            app_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    return os.path.join(app_dir, path)
```

For the second issue instead of tree i use the wildcard operator (*) to add what i need.

```py
added_files = [
         ( './pics/*', 'pics' ),
         ( './db/*', 'db' ),
         ]
```

then in Analysis,

```
datas = added_files
```

A thorough answer is quite long. I've written [this article](https://www.pythonkitchen.com/packaging-an-sqlite-db-included-crud-pyqt5-app-using-pyinstaller/) to show in some minute details what i went through to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[@ Answer from above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20677118/21297991)

There is no way this will work because spec build doesn't support      --onefile.

Per Pyinstaller error message:

`option(s) not allowed: --onedir/--onefile --console/--nowindowed/--windowed/--noconsole makespec options not valid when a .spec file is given`

Unless it was supported on older version. I tried every version back to 3.0 at which point I stopped because I would have been forced to break dependencies and go on a dependency chase.

Unfortunately if you include the folders individually with
`--path` they become flattened in directory that your `script.py` resides, unless you provide each file individually with `--add-data SRC:DEST` arguments.