# pyinstaller add folder beside executable exe?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

i'm trying to add folder called 'old method' beside my executable script and am gonna make it one exe program but the problem is i need to add this folder to Collecting together .

i tried it by that method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602727/pyinstaller-generate-exe-file-folder-in-onefile-mode)  using a Tree but it doesn't seems work with python3 so my spec files contain :

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['main.py'],

     pathex=['C:\\Users\\Fathy\\Desktop\\ZRender'],

     binaries=[],

     datas=[],

     hiddenimports=[],

     hookspath=[],

     runtime_hooks=[],

     excludes=[],

     win_no_prefer_redirects=False,

     win_private_assemblies=False,

     cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,

     cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,

  a.scripts,

  exclude_binaries=True,

  name='main',

  debug=False,

  strip=False,

  upx=True,

  console=True )

coll = COLLECT(exe,

       a.binaries,

       Tree[("old method"],

       a.zipfiles,

       a.datas,

       strip=False,

       upx=True,

       name='main')
```