# Convert python scripts with images to exe file

Tags: python, exe

I need to make an exe file from several python scripts.
I have main python file that calls 2 other python scripts. In addition The scripts need few images that present in the same folder.

How do i make this whole to a single exe file?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-can-i-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [a good python to exe compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165398/a-good-python-to-exe-compiler)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller: generate -exe file + folder (in --onefile mode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602727/pyinstaller-generate-exe-file-folder-in-onefile-mode)

Comment: If you are looking for single exe go with the low level language c & c++ Python may not produce single exe. you can use cx_Freeze library to convert exe. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/how-can-i-convert-a-py-to-exe-for-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto-py-to-exe module of python...

Comment: pyinstaller was the answer I just had to modify the spec file