# PyInstaller Tree Cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller

I want to include a folder and its contents within pyinstaller. I have a folder named 'etc' and it has a file named sbom.json. I am following the post mentioned [tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602727/pyinstaller-generate-exe-file-folder-in-onefile-mode/20677118#20677118), but I keep getting an error saying `The system cannot find the path specified: '..\\etc` when I run `pyinstaller fetch_sbom_packages.spec` command.

(The fetch_sbom_packages.py has dependencies with dsapi.py and shared.py).

Here is my folder structure. I want to include the etc folder and its contents

[image: folder.]

Here is the fetch_sbom_packages.spec

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['fetch_sbom_packages.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    Tree('..\\etc', prefix='etc\\'),
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='fetch_sbom_packages',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

Comment: I deleted one question. Sorry I didn't notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That post is from 9+ years ago.

What you want to do is add a tuple to the `datas` parameter in the Analysis for the folder you want to be included in the compiled app.

For example:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['fetch_sbom_packages.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[("./etc", "./etc")],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='fetch_sbom_packages',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```