# pyinstaller multiple py files import in an exe, error when creating process

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I am currently developing a GUI in PyQt5
I have several py files:

- 1) program.py
- 2) content.py

**1) program.py**

This contains some additions such as actions by pressing a button as well as the import of the icon.

**2) content.py**

Here is where the graphic part of the program is, this one had created it with **PyQt5 designer**, and converted to py with pyuic5.

when I link with python:

```
pyinstaller program.py
```

it is an error and I have also tried creating a **.py** file that links to both **.py** and p files..

**link.py**

```
#contains

import program.py
import contenido.py
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including a directory using Pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322538/including-a-directory-using-pyinstaller)

Comment: gracias @eyllanesc

Comment: alguna vez te ha pasado este problema?, solo quiero convertir a exe mi codigo y no puedo hacerlo

Comment: @eyllanesc you can make an example of how the spec is used