# Distributing Python App Without the use of PIP

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, software-distribution

I have a python app that I intend to distribute in download/install style format (like a traditional desktop app) instead of packaging it for pip, but all of the instructions I can find online are designed for PyPI. My file structure:

```
/MatrixKontrol/
   /saves/
      /example/
         example.json
   edit.py
   functions.py
   main.py
   savecreate.py
   saveload.py
```

I would like to have this a complete system, so executables for Darwin/Linux/Windows.

Note: I need to maintain the `/saves/` directory for application saves.

Comment: See [python packaging overview](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/overview/) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/1558385

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use PyInstaller. More information on it can be found [here](https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/).

Comment: Is there a cross platform alternative to PyInstaller?

Comment: PyInstaller supports MacOS, Windows, and Linux in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Will it work with that folder that needs to be maintained?

Comment: It will. There are trees (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11322538/including-a-directory-using-pyinstaller) as one option. Worse case scenario, you could even create new folders during program execution.